# Delete CD icon from desktop

Tags: kali-linux, desktop

So after installing Kali on my VM I'm left with the CD icon on desktop (Kali Live CD). How can I actually delete it? Same thing happens when I try to install VMware Tools

Cut/Move options are disabled after RMB

Comment: You should **eject** the icon (most desktops make a distinction versus **delete**).

Comment: Not even an eject option

Comment: Try "man eject".

Comment: "man eject" on what?

Comment: In a terminal :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you cannot find a suitable menu entry on your desktop, do it in a terminal:

- open a terminal (probably called *Terminal*)
- in the terminal, type

  sudo eject
- close the terminal by typing `exit` (or <kbd>control</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>)

Further reading:

- [eject - eject removable media](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/eject.1.html)
- [How to eject a CD/DVD from the command line](https://askubuntu.com/questions/226638/how-to-eject-a-cd-dvd-from-the-command-line)
- [Problems Installing VMware Tools When the Guest CD-ROM Drive Is Locked](https://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2107)
- [Simple way to open your cd/dvd drive with one click in Ubuntu 10.04.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PPK_jxbN3yY)

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the icon and select Eject